# select unknown no of columns as csv

Tags: sql-server-2008

Say I have unknown N columns in a table and a primary key column so I want all the columns of a particular primary key in CSV format.

N can be any number of columns

```
ID Name    Class   RollNo  Language  State   Country

1  Aditya  12th    5       English   C.A.    USA

2  XYZ     X       3        AA       AA      AAA
```

Output should be like

```
1,Aditya,12th,5,English,CA,USA

2,XYZ,X,3,AA,AA,AAA
```

in  SQL SERVER

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
       DECLARE @sql        VARCHAR(8000),
        @dbname     VARCHAR(50)='',
        @schemaname VARCHAR(50)='dbo',
        @tablename  VARCHAR(50)=''

SELECT @sql = 'bcp ' + @dbname + '.' + @schemaname + '.'
              + @tablename
              + ' out
c:\bcp\tablename.csv -u username -p password -S'
              + @@SERVERNAME
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell
  @sql

--[Note:The path should be your server path]
--TO configure xp_cmdshell
EXEC sp_configure
  'show advanced options',
  1;

GO

-- To update the currently configured value for advanced options.
RECONFIGURE;

GO

-- To enable the feature.
EXEC sp_configure
  'xp_cmdshell',
  1;

GO

-- To update the currently configured value for this feature.
RECONFIGURE;

GO
```

Comment: i dont want a csv file i just want it as rows returned in sql